# extend docker image preserving its entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have created an image that has an entrypoint script that is run on container start. I use this image for different purposes. Now, I want to extend this image, but it needs to modify some files in the container before starting the container but after the image creation. So the second image will also have an entrypoint script. So, do I just call the base image's entrypoint script from the second image's entrypoint script? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An image only has one `ENTRYPOINT` (and one `CMD`).  In the situation you describe, your new entrypoint needs to explicitly call the old one.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# new-entrypoint.sh

# modify some files in the container
sed -e 's/PLACEHOLDER/value/g' /etc/config.tmpl > /etc/config

# run the original entrypoint; make sure to pass the CMD along
exec original-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Remember that setting `ENTRYPOINT` in a derived Dockerfile also resets `CMD` so you'll have to restate this.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["new-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD original command from base image
```

It's also worth double-checking to see if the base image has some extension facility or another path to inject configuration files.  Most of the standard database images will run initialization scripts from a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, which can be bind-mounted, and so you can avoid a custom image for this case; the `nginx` image knows how substitute environment variables; in many cases you can `docker run -v` to bind-mount a directory of config files into a container.  Those approaches can be easier than replacing or wrapping `ENTRYPOINT`.